# findstr search including return character

Tags: batch-file, findstr

Is there a way I can use `findstr` to search for:

```
<char>Hello there my friend,</char>
<continued>this is two lines of text</continued>
```

I need to search for a string that includes a second line. I've tried something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set file=test.txt
set LF=^


:: The above 2 blank lines MUST be preserved!
findstr /RC:"hello!LF!there" "test.txt" >nul
if %errorlevel%==0 echo found 1!
pause
```

where test.txt contains:

```
oh
hello
there
friends
how are
you
```

But it is not triggered.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8773526/9882907) may work for you.

Comment: I think that is key to what I am looking for, but how can I customize that to look for a specified match in a text file? I can't seem to figure out where the author is setting the search string. @Worthwelle

Comment: The search string is in the line `for /f "delims=" %%A in ('cmd /v:on /c^"findstr /rc:"Item No\. .*^!CR^!*^!LF^!.* Exception: " %file%^"') do (`. Specifically, `"Item No\. .*^!CR^!*^!LF^!.* Exception: "`. The `^!CR^!*^!LF^!` is the "Carriage Return" and "Line Feed", which Windows uses to signify the end of a line.

Comment: Ok, editing it does not seem to be working. What are the other lines in the for loop for? I just want to know if there is a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Find if there are any matches

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set file=test.txt
set line1=hello
set line2=there
set LF=^


:: The above 2 blank lines MUST be preserved!
:: Define a CR variable as a CarriageReturn (0x0D) character
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"

cmd /v:on /c^"findstr /rc:"%line1%^!CR^!*^!LF^!%line2%" %file%^" >nul
if %errorlevel%==0 echo found at least 1!
pause
```

This batch file adds in a check for the Carriage Return character, which is necessary for text files with Windows-style newlines (`CR LF`). It also runs `findstr` in a separate `cmd` process with Delayed Expansion enabled. This seems to be necessary, even though delayed expansion is already enabled.

Lastly, this includes two variables: `line1` and `line2`, which can be edited. This makes the file more readable for editing in the future. You can also include the same Regular Expression variables in this, so `hell.` would match `hello`, etc.

## Find the number of matches

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set file=test.txt
set line1=hell.
set line2=there
set LF=^


:: The above 2 blank lines MUST be preserved!
:: Define a CR variable as a CarriageReturn (0x0D) character
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"

set results=0
for /f %%a in ('cmd /v:on /c^"findstr /rc:"%line1%^!LF^!%line2%" %file%^"') do set /A results+=1
echo found %results%!
pause
```

The notable difference here is the `for /f` surrounding the search and `set /A results+=1`, which adds 1 to the `results` variable for each match found.

## Further reading:

- [`FINDSTR` - SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [`FOR` - SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`SET /A` - SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html#expressions)
- [Capturing CR LF - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8773526/9882907)

Comment: Can I vote for this to be question of the year? : D